# Why didn't Aragorn Let Theoden kill Grima?

Tags: character, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

After Gandalf released Theoden from Saruman's spell in *The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers*, Theoden wants to kill Grima for making him "crawl on all fours like a beast". 
But Aragorn stops him saying "enough blood has been spilled because of him".

Why wouldn't he just let him die, he surely deserved it!

Comment: one word: nobility.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a recurring theme in The Lord Of The Rings, both novels and movie, that showing mercy towards wrongdoers is an act of highest morality, and that killing should be done only for defense, not for revenge.

The clearest example of this is Gollum. In the first movie there's this bit of dialogue, taken verbatim from the books:

```
                    FRODO
                    (grim)
         It's a pity Bilbo didn't kill him when he
         had the chance.

                   GANDALF
         Pity? It was pity that stayed Bilbo's
         hand. Many that live deserve death, and
         some that die deserve life. Can you give
         it to them, Frodo? 

Frodo frowns.

                   GANDALF (CONT'D)
         Do not be too eager to deal out death in
         judgment...even the very wise cannot see
         all ends. My heart tells me that Gollum
         has some part to play yet, for good or
         ill, before this is over. The pity of
         Bilbo may rule the fate of many.
```

This sentiment by Gandalf is, of course, foreshadowing Gollum's importance later on, and his essential role in destroying the ring.

Aragorn, in this case, is showing the same mercy that he doubtless learned from Gandalf. And not surprisingly, the same mercy does, later, come back to help the good guys, to Saruman's downfall - in the books he is responsible for Aragorn taking possession of the Palantir and later on for Saruman's death during the Scouring of the Shire. In the movie, we have this scene in the Extended Edition of the Return of the King where Grima redeems himself:

```
Grima Wormtongue appears behind Saruman. 

                              THEODEN    
               Grima! You need not follow him! You were 
               not always as you are now. You were once 
               a man of Rohan. Come down. 

Grima looks like he going to come down. 

[..]

                              THEODEN
               Grima…. Come down! Be free of him! 

                              SARUMAN   
               Free? He will never be free!

                              GRIMA 
               No!  

 Saruman turns around to Grima! 

                              SARUMAN
               Get down cur! (slaps him to the ground) 

                              GRIMA
               Ah! 

[..]

Grima rises up behind Saruman and attacks him with the knife, 
stabbing him twice in the back. Legolas aims an arrow at Grima 
who falls shot in the heart. Saruman falls from the tower and is 
impaled on a great wheel below.
```

Comment: Why would Legolas shoot Grima there, if he was doing what they wanted?

Comment: @TankorSmash In the books, this was accomplished by the Epilogue of the Purging of the Shire, where Grima does the same thing to Saruman, but in a less dramatic circumstance (but isn't killed for it, IIRC). Call it movie logic, I guess. They needed to figure out SOME way to get rid of the character, since movie morality works that way.

Comment: @TankorSmash: They do not want Saruman dead; Saruman has valuable intelligence about what Sauron plans to do next. They want him alive but powerless.

Comment: @EricLippert True, but, still, why shoot Grima after he's already stabbed Saruman? It's not like killing Grima is going to bring Saruman back. This seems to violate the same mercy principle mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @reirab: That is a good question. In the movies, Leggy's core competencies seem pretty limited to shooting bad dudes with arrows and defying physics.

Comment: It honestly made a lot more sense in the books - Grima was attacking Saruman in front of a large crowd, and the crowd got excited (so to speak), resulting in several people taking aim at Saruman. Grima caught some of the stray arrows because of his sheer proximity to Saruman. I *guess* Legolas's shot in the movie was maybe supposed to be accidental/friendly fire in the movie, but it doesn't really make much sense and it certainly didn't look like an accident.

Comment: Also - speaking of comparing the books to the movies, in the books, it was actually Aragorn who wanted to kill Grima, and Theoden who didn't want any more killing - if I recall correctly, it had more to do with grief/"there has been enough violence in one day" (remember that for Theoden, the death of his son was just then sinking in, and he'd also thought of Grima as a friend - or at least, a valued adviser - up to that point, so he has all sorts of conflicting feelings over whether he really wants to see somebody else close to him die.)

Comment: Congratulation for wining [additional bounty as consolation](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1848/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2015)  prize for being 3rd highest score in event.

Comment: @reirab Little late to the party, but here are my two cents: I'm sure Legolas tried to stop Grima from killing Saruman. Everyone would want to try it at least, because it's hard to say Saruman was already dead.